# IOS 11 Navigation Bar Button Item

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11

We were using the below code to show leftbarbutton item in our navigation bar in IOS 10 SDK and XCode 8, however when we updated to xcode9 and ios 11 sdk. The left bar button item doesnt show. I searched through the web , but couldnt find any solution to that.
Does anyone know any answer?

```
UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = nil;

if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"11")) {
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 35)];
    //button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -15, 0, 15);
    //button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(13, 8, 13, 8);
    NSLayoutConstraint *widthConst = [button.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:32.0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *heightConst = [button.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:32.0];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cross"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(hide) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

    widthConst.active = YES;
    heightConst.active = YES;

} else {
    cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cross"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:loginRouter action:@selector(hide)];

}

cancelButton.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
loginViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton;


loginRouter.loginViewController = loginViewController;

CardNavigationController *navigationController = [CardNavigationController darkBlueNavigationControllerWithClient:client];
navigationController.viewControllers = @[ loginViewController ];
navigationController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

[onViewController presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And you can find the result in ios 11 below

[image]

Comment: Try putting `loginViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton;` after `navigationController.viewControllers = @[ loginViewController ];` Or just before `present..`

Comment: that didnt work also

Comment: @tolgatanriverdi Can you post a small project that would demonstrate the issue?

Comment: still couldnt find any solution does anyone have any idea about the problem?

Comment: Did you get to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following example

```
UIImage *imgCart = [self imageWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_cart"] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(35, 35)] ;

imgCart = [_utils changeColorOf:imgCart to:[UIColor whiteColor]];
UIButton *btnCart = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
[btnCart addTarget:self action:@selector(btnCartClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btnCart setBackgroundImage:imgCart forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnCart];
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not work when you set 'cancelButton.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor]' in ios11. you can use the method "setTitleTextAttributes".